# Type 'SelectedDelieveryTimeDateSloteDS' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' in swift

Tags: swift, codable

```
struct SelectedDelieveryTimeDateSloteDS: Decodable {
    let method: String
    let entityID: Int?
    let name, methods: String?
    let active: Bool
    let sortOrder, futureDaysLimit, startDaysLimit, shippingMethodsChoiceLimiter: Int?
    let workingDays, cutOffTime: String?
    let quotesScope: Int?
    let storeIDS: [Int]
    let customerGroupIDS: [Any?]
    let dayLimits: [DayLimitDS]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case method
        case entityID = "entity_id" // Match the JSON key
        case name
        case methods
        case active
        case sortOrder
        case futureDaysLimit
        case startDaysLimit
        case shippingMethodsChoiceLimiter
        case workingDays
        case cutOffTime
        case quotesScope
        case storeIDS
        case customerGroupIDS
        case dayLimits
    }
}
```

this is my api calling in swift:

```
 let apiUrl = URL(string: "https://www.abcCart.com/rest/V1/delivery_date/230699/0")!

                    // Create a URLRequest
                    var request = URLRequest(url: apiUrl)
                    request.httpMethod = "GET"

                    // Set the headers
                    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    request.setValue("Bearer bdvhxoi4c2m079ps5hp6mrzshvcmwiso", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

                    // Create a URLSession task to make the API call
                    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error: \(error)")
                            return
                        }
                        
                        guard let data = data else {
                            print("No data received")
                            return
                        }
                        
                        do {
                            // Parse the JSON response
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let result = try decoder.decode(SelectedDelieveryTimeDateSloteDS.self, from: data)
                            
                            // Now you can work with the 'result' object
                            print(result)
                            debugPrint("TimeSloteCheck_result: \(result)")
                            
                        } catch let parseError {
                            print("Error parsing JSON: \(parseError)")
                        }
                    }

                    // Start the URLSession task
                    task.resume()
```

why i am facing this on struck module.

Comment: `let customerGroupIDS: [Any?]`, you can’t use `Any` with `Codable`

Comment: ok, how to handle this becuase of this empty in

Comment: Please complete the comment above. Or use https://quicktype.io/ to get help creating custom types for your json.

Comment: Each property of a `Decodable` struct needs to be `Decodable`. When you have this kind of error, you can create an alternative struct, let's call it: `struct SelectedDelieveryTimeDateSloteDSTest: Decodable {}`, and add each property of the original one by one until you find the culprit. Here, `Any` is not `Decodable`. You can replace `Decodable` with `Encodable` or `Codable` in my previous sentences.

Comment: OK, this module quicktype.io create